# weighted random selection in java?

Tags: java, random

Can I do the following in java without using external libraries? Maybe with if-else statements?
thanks

```
import random

print(random.choices(['A', 'B', 'C'], [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure. The tools required are:

- an instance of `java.util.Random`
- call its [`nextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) method.

The algorithm is something like:

- First calculate, once-off, the incremental weighting. In your example that would be `[0.5, 0.8, 1.0]`.
- Multiply the output of `nextDouble` with the final weight (here the final weight is 1.0, so not needed. Multiplying by 1.0 doesn't hurt, of course).
- loop through the incremental weights and check if the random number you have is less than it. If yes, that's your choice.

Example:

```
public class WeightedList {
    private final char[] choices;
    private final double[] weights;
    private final Random rnd = new Random();

    public WeightedList(char[] choices, double[] weights) {
        if (choices.length != weights.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.choices = Arrays.copyOf(choices);
        this.weights = new double[weights.length];
        double s = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
            this.weights[i] = (s += weights[i]);
        }
    }

    public char get() {
        double v = rnd.nextDouble() * weights[weights.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length - 1; i++) {
            if (v < weights[i]) return choices[i];
        }
        return weights[weights.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: I made the code (specifically the `get()` method) a tiny bit prettier.